# c# Xamarin Android application - VideoView streaming starts after >30seconds since Google API 28

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-videoview

I have a Xamarin Android application, written in Visual Studio 2017. It's working fine, but now I have to publish on Google Play an update, so I have to build it using API Level 28 (Pie). My application is accessing videos from the net (uploaded on a server), and shows those clips on a VideoView control.

With the new API (28) on some phones (Huawei, Samsung) the videos are starting very-very slow (after 30-40 seconds), even if the application is opening them externally (I tried this too: *Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new Uri(video_url)* - the same result, a slow start on the problematic phones).

On the same phones, if I directly open those links from their browser, the videos are starting instantly... If I use the actual, API 26 version of my application, the videos are starting also instantly (in 2-3 seconds). So it's clear to me that this is a API 28 problem.

On other phones this problem does not occurred, the application works correctly (as with the API Level 26 version which workes fine on every type of phones).

Can somebody help me with some ideas what I could try to solve this slow streaming problem?

SOLUTION: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600)

It was the Cleartext Trafic permission...

Comment: Could you please post more details about this question(e.g. some code snippet), so that others could help you better?

Comment: It's nothing special in the code, a VideoView, with the setting up part and start. With API 26 works fine, with API 28 on some phones is starting late, after 30 seconds...